# Creating a 2D arrow in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am using unity 2d to create a golf game, currently I have a golf ball that you can click on, drag your mouse back and let go to fire the ball.
I would like to add an arrow that starts where you click and ends where you let go to see the direction of aim.

I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to do this or where to begin.
Any help on this or if you could push me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a world-space UI canvas and draw an arrow on it. There are many ways you can do the second half, but a good place to start would be to get a UI canvas in there and start toying with ways that you can make objects in that behave.

For more on world-space UI, refer [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the position where you click. You can get the mouse position with Input.mousePosition. More information about this [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html).
While holding the click, you have to store a second mouse position, this one will save the current position.
Use, for example, a [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) linking both positions. If you want the arrow aiming to the opposite direction i.e. the position where the ball will be fired, just set the second position to negative.